# Spark groupby sum for all columns except 1

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset with header like this:

```
|State|2020-01-22|2020-01-23|2020-01-24|2020-01-25|2020-01-26|2020-01-27|2020-01-28|
```

and I am trying to `groupBy` based on `State` column and the sum of row values for each column(The number of columns remains the same). But when I do it using:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.groupBy('State').agg(F.sum())
```

But I get the error: `sum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'col'`
How do I get the sum of row values for each column. I also tried this:

```
df = df.groupBy('State').agg(F.sum('2020-01-22','2020-01-23'))
```

and I get an error: `sum() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension to iterate all columns except the grouper

```
 df.groupBy('State').agg(*[sum(i).alias(f"sum_{i}") for i in df.drop('State').columns]).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply note that the `GroupedData` object returned by `df.groupBy()` has a `sum` method that sums up all columns when passed no arguments:

```
>>> df.show()
+-----+---+---+
|state|  a|  b|
+-----+---+---+
|    a|  5|  5|
|    a|  6|  6|
|    b| 10| 10|
+-----+---+---+

>>> df.groupBy("state").sum().show()
+-----+------+------+
|state|sum(a)|sum(b)|
+-----+------+------+
|    b|    10|    10|
|    a|    11|    11|
+-----+------+------+
```